# how to change single python exe Bot to multiple user?

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, multiprocessing

I have created python bot for back-end process.It will fetch data from the website and return the data , Now BOT exe in 4GB RAM system ,I have to use same exe for multiple user in parallel manner without affecting the RAM,Is it possible ? Please guide me for better approach.At-least for 10 user .